# check if user posted a message in last 24 hours

Tags: php, datetime

I am making a script to check if an user has posted a message in less then 24 hours.

I use these SQL query, but the result always give me 0. I am sure there is a post within 24 hours in the database but i get 0 as result.

datum in the database has a datetime string.

```
 $sqll = "SELECT * FROM berichtenbalk WHERE naam = '".$_SESSION['firstname']."' AND datum < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;";
```

What im doing wrong??
I am sure session firstname has the good input.

Thanks
Marv

Comment: `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` is in the past and you want posts with timestamps _greater_ than that, so use `>`.

Comment: and never, ever, compose SQL the way you're doing: use prepared statements that make that `naam` value actually safe.

Comment: Thanks Sammiitch. That's the trick.